# How to let user know that radio button and drop down list are auto PostBack?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, webforms

I have this transaction list web page that let user filter records by using `transaction number`, `transaction date`, `transaction status`, `transaction department`, and many more.

`transaction status` is using radio button.

`transaction department` is using drop down list.

How do I let user know that if they select option in radio buttons or drop down list, they do not need to press the `Filter` button because of auto PostBack but for the rest of the filter fields, they will have to press the `Filter` button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of special indication.
You can just refresh the list as soon as the user selects some values in that field,
and as the list reloads he will understand that his parameter has been applied as a filter and the results are produced.
You should give a loading screen so that user attention diverts there. and he will get to know that as he did some action this is happening.

Comment: It seems like my user don't know that because they actually ask me should they press the filter button.

Comment: u should give a splash screen i.e., a loading screen so that his attention diverts to that place. I will edit my answer.